# doing unit testing of image upload and getting image size, angular

Tags: angular, jestjs

I am trying to write UT for getting image dimension on upload, my function in angular is like this:

```
onFileSelected(event: FileList) {
    const file: File = event[0];
    const uploadSuccess: boolean = this.validateFile(file);
    if (uploadSuccess) {
      this.selectedFile.emit(file);
    }
  }

getImageDimensions(chosenFile): void {
    const CHOSEN_URL = window.URL || window.webkitURL;
    const Img = new Image();
 
    Img.src = CHOSEN_URL.createObjectURL(chosenFile);
    console.log(Img, CHOSEN_URL.createObjectURL(chosenFile));
    Img.onload = (e: any) => {
      const height = e.path[0].height;
      const width = e.path[0].width;
      if (width > this.uploaderParams.extras['maxImgWidth'] || height > this.uploaderParams.extras['maxImgHeight']) {
        this.showError(
          'Error',
          `Max file size is width: ${this.uploaderParams.extras['maxImgWidth']} height: ${this.uploaderParams.extras['maxImgHeight']}`,
          3000
        );
        return false;
      } else {
        this.selectedFile.emit(chosenFile);
      }
    };
    
  }
```

In unit test i doing like this:

```
  import { async, ComponentFixture, fakeAsync, flush, flushMicrotasks, TestBed, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

{more import..}

function MockFile() { };

MockFile.prototype.create = function (name, size, mimeType) {
    name = name || "mock.txt";
    size = size || 1024;
    mimeType = mimeType || 'plain/txt';

    function range(count) {
        let output = "";
        for (let i = 0; i < count; i++) {
            output += "a";
        }
        return output;
    }

    const blob = new Blob([range(size)], { type: mimeType });
    blob['lastModifiedDate'] = new Date();
    blob['name'] = name;

    return blob;
};

fdescribe('FileUploadComponent', () => {
  let component: FileUploadComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<FileUploadComponent>;

  window.URL.createObjectURL = jest.fn(() => {
    return "blob:http://localhost:4200/eadb7d52-51bf-47ce-9eee-b9abaadb86f4";
  });


  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [FileUploadComponent],
      imports: [
        ToastrModule.forRoot(),
        NoopAnimationsModule
      ],
      providers: [
        { provide: ToastService, useValue: toastrService },
        { provide: ToastPackage, useValue: toastPackageMock }
      ],
      schemas: [NO_ERRORS_SCHEMA],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(FileUploadComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    fixture.destroy();
    // window.URL.createObjectURL.mockReset();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should trigger onFileSelected', fakeAsync(() => {
    const prev_value = {};
    const new_value = uploaderParams;
    const is_first_change = false;

    const size = 1024 * 1024 * .8;
    const mock = new MockFile();
    const file = mock.create("pic.jpg", size, "image/jpeg");
    expect(file).not.toBeNull();
    const fileList = {
      0: file,
      1: file,
      length: 2,
      item: (index: number) => file
    };
    component.uploaderParams = uploaderParams;
    component.ngOnChanges({ prop1: new SimpleChange(prev_value, new_value, is_first_change) });

    fixture.detectChanges();
    fixture.whenStable();
    component.onFileSelected(fileList);

  }));

});
```

The problem is the unit test is not going inside  `Img.onload` method.  Please help.

Comment: Are you using *Jest*, or *Jasmine* - that's the second question you've tagged with both.

Comment: Using jest,. I am using, NX.